# Android Database null fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

It keeps saying

```
     getReadableDatabse cant be invoked on null object which is the database.
```

So my DataBase is null for some reason.

DBHelper:

```
// Create tables or drop if new version
public dbHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public Athlete getLastInsertedAthlete(){

    Log.e("", "TEST!!!!!!!!");

    Athlete athlete = new Athlete();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + COL_ATHLETE_ID + ") AS " + COL_ATHLETE_ID + ", " +
            COL_FIRST_NAME + ", " + COL_LAST_NAME + ", " + COL_AGE + ", " + COL_GRADE +
            " FROM " + TABLE_ATHLETES, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int lastAthleteID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ATHLETE_ID));
    Log.e("", "Athlete ID: " + lastAthleteID);
    athlete.setAthleteID(lastAthleteID);

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_EVENT + " FROM " + TABLE_ATHLETES +
    " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_ATHLETES_EVENTS + " ON " + TABLE_ATHLETES + "." + COL_ATHLETE_ID +
            " = " + TABLE_ATHLETES_EVENTS + "." + COL_ATHLETE_ID +
            " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_EVENTS + " ON " + TABLE_ATHLETES_EVENTS + "." + COL_EVENT_ID +
            " = " + TABLE_EVENTS + "." + COL_EVENT_ID +
            " WHERE " + TABLE_ATHLETES + "." + COL_ATHLETE_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(athlete.getAthleteID())});

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    athlete.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_FIRST_NAME)));
    athlete.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_LAST_NAME)));
    athlete.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_AGE)));
    athlete.setGrade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_GRADE)));

     int i = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String event = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_EVENT));
            athlete.addEvent(event);
            Log.e("", "Events: " + athlete.getEvents().get(i));
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return athlete;
}
```

Main Activity: sent from fragment a to activity and activity updates fragment B

```
// Sends athlete information to athlete list
@Override
public void send(String confirmation) {
    if(confirmation == "Athlete Added!") {
        AthletesList athletesList = getAthleteListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, athletesList, "athletesList");
        athletesList.addAthleteToList();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: message confirmation incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public AthletesList getAthleteListFragment(){
    AthletesList athletesList = (AthletesList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("athletesList");
    if(athletesList == null){
        athletesList = new AthletesList();
    }
    return athletesList;
}
```

Create DataBase instance here in Activity created. This is a Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    db = new dbHelper(getActivity());
}
```

Gets to the first log message but then says my DataBase is `null`.

```
public void addAthleteToList(){
    Log.e("", "Getting to addAthleteToList()");
    db.getReadableDatabase();
    Athlete athlete = db.getLastInsertedAthlete();
    db.close();
    Log.e("", "Athlete ID to be added: " + athlete.getAthleteID());
```

Comment: post you code so we can understand more

Comment: Added my main activity code that calls addAthleteToList() function on the Fragment

Comment: what about dbHelper class

Comment: added helper class, a basic helper class that creates database if not created, but it is already created

Comment: You already called  `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` in `DBHelper` class. So no need to write again in fragment  `db.getReadableDatabase();`

Comment: You should post all your `DbHelper` class.

Comment: Post the complete code of DB. We can't identify where the database is being created and its structure.

Answer (score 0):

The `db` is only initialized in `onActivityCreated()` in the fragment lifecycle but you're calling `addAthleteToList()` immediately after constructing the fragment. The lifecycle method is not run yet.

Generally, do not call fragment methods outside of the fragment lifecycle callbacks. To pass data to a fragment from the outside, use a `Bundle` and `setArguments()`. Postpone code that needs a `Context` or `Activity` until the fragment is attached to one i.e. `onAttach()` or later in the lifecycle.

There are other problems in the code as well, such as string comparison with `==` and not checking the result of `moveToFirst()`.

Comment: I was taught to call fragment methods from the activity in order to make fragments reusable so how would I go about postponing code until the fragment is attached.